# Can someone show how is this integration done step by step?

Tags: integration

I am reading a problem of diffusion equation, and there is a part that I couldn't understand how it is done.

$$ u_n(t)=-\frac {2n\pi k}{l^2}\int_0^te^{-\lambda_nk(t-s) }\big [ (-1)^nj(s)-h(s)\big ]ds$$ 
,where $h(t)\equiv 0, j(t)=At, $ $A$ is constant. 
$$ u_n(t)=(-1)^{n+1}\frac {2n\pi kA}{l^2}e^{-\lambda_nkt}\int_0^te^{\lambda_nks}\qquad(*)$$

Comment: Are you asking the steps as to how the first integral becomes the second one?

Comment: I mean how is the first integral simplified so that we got the equation $(*)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed something. Use integration by parts. With $h(t)=0$ and $j(t)=At$ we have
$$u_n(t)=-\frac {2n\pi k}{l^2}\int_0^te^{-\lambda_nk(t-s) }\big [ (-1)^nj(s)-h(s)\big ]ds=-\frac {2n\pi k}{l^2}e^{-\lambda_nk(t) }(-1)^nA\int_0^t se^{\lambda_nks }ds$$ 
now let $u=s$ and $e^{\lambda_nks }ds=dv$ and hence $du=ds$ and $\dfrac{1}{{\lambda_nk}}e^{\lambda_nks}=v$, so with $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$, then 
$$\int_0^t se^{\lambda_nks }ds=s\dfrac{1}{{\lambda_nk}}e^{\lambda_nks}\Big|_0^t-\dfrac{1}{{\lambda_nk}}\int_0^t e^{\lambda_nks }ds=t\dfrac{1}{{\lambda_nk}}e^{\lambda_nkt}-\dfrac{1}{{\lambda_nk}}\int_0^t e^{\lambda_nks }ds$$
and you can simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that for any constant $\;k\neq0\;$ we have

$$\int e^{kx}dx=\frac1ke^{kx}+C\implies \int_0^1 e^{\lambda_nks}ds=\left.\frac1{\lambda_nk}e^{\lambda_nks}\right|_0^1=\frac{e^{\lambda_nk}-1}{\lambda_nk}$$